# Kerning between f and footnote mark

Tags: luatex, kerning

Adapting code from an answer by U. Fischer, I hoped this might fix a problem
with the footnote marks in IM Fell, which touch a preceding f.  But it doesn't.
How should this be done?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\directlua {
    fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature {
        name = "ktest",
             type = "kern",
             data = {
                 ["f"] = { 
                     ["o"] =  1000,
                     ["1"] = 1000,
                     ["¹"] = 1000
                 },
             },
    }
}

\setmainfont{imfellenglish}[RawFeature=+ktest]

\begin{document}

foof\footnote{barb.}.

\end{document}
```

[image: f touching 1]

UPDATE:

The realscripts package makes `\textsuperscript` and `\footnote` access superscript glyphs, but the new kerning is ignored.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{realscripts}

\directlua {
    fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature {
        name = "ktest",
        type = "kern",
        data = {
            ["f"] = { 
        ["⁵"] = 1000,
      }
        }
    }
}

\setmainfont{ebgaramond}[RawFeature=+ktest]

\begin{document}

\noindent
f⁴\\
f⁵\\
f\textsuperscript{5}\\
f\footnote{test}\\
f\footnote{test}\\
f\footnote{test}\\
f\footnote{test}\\
f\footnote{test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

PS III.  Not even changing the otf with fontforge works.

Comment: I don't have the font, but imho the superscript is from a smaller font and then kerning doesn't applay. You would need real superscripts to get get kerning. Check the realscript package.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, thanks, I'll look at it.  The font is in texlive.

Comment: Ups. Sorry I was in the wrong texsystem. I just looked the font doesn't have +sups. So kerning won't work.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, I tried with ebgaramond too (and realscripts), but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `realscript` will not help: In the end you will still use two different fonts -- the main font and the superscript font with the +sups open type tag.

So if you want to solve your problem with kerning you need to redefine `\textsuperscript` so that it directly access the superscript glyphs (the example works only for 1--5) and to get `\footnote` working you will also need to redefine the command that set the footnotemark -- it could have side effects as one has to remove a \nobreak. The numbers used in the example are font specific. For a general solution one need some way to access the glyphs by name.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}


\directlua {
    fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature {
        name = "ktest",
        type = "kern",
        data = {
            ["f"] = {
        ["one.sups"] = 1000,
        [983449] = 1000,
        [983450] = 1000,    
        [983451] = 1000,
        [983452] = 1000,
      }
        }
    }
}

\setmainfont{ebgaramond}[RawFeature=+ktest]

\begin{document}

\renewcommand\textsuperscript[1]{%
 \ifcase #1 
 \or \symbol{983448}%one.sups 
 \or \symbol{983449}%two.sups 
 \or \symbol{983450}%three.sups 
 \or \symbol{983451}%four.sups
 \or \symbol{983452}%five.sups
 \fi}

\makeatletter 
\renewcommand\@makefnmark{\textsuperscript{\@thefnmark}}

\def\@footnotemark{%
  \leavevmode
  \ifhmode\edef\@x@sf{\the\spacefactor}%\nobreak
  \fi
  \@makefnmark
  \ifhmode\spacefactor\@x@sf\fi
  \relax}

f\footnote{test} \\
f\footnote{test}\\
f\footnote{test}\\
f\footnote{test}\\
f\footnote{test}

f\textsuperscript{1}
f\textsuperscript{2}
f\textsuperscript{3}
f\textsuperscript{4}
f\textsuperscript{5}

\end{document}
```

[image]